Can't start VNC server on baremetal remote instance
I have been following several tutorials to use VNC on my remote baremetal instance (chameleon cloud). I had to install a bunch of things since it did not have a GUI interface. I want to use this instance through the GUI.
Some details about my instance: I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS jammy x86_64. I use this instance through ssh. My xstartup file looks like this:
#!/bin/sh
# Unset environment variables
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

# Start the D-Bus session
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID

# Set the display environment variable
export DISPLAY=:1

# Start XFCE
startxfce4 &

I have been using this configuration since I found it on the internet. I will be happy to change it.
When I start my VNC server I get the following output:
New Xtigervnc server 'new-emu:1 (cc)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/cc/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/cc/.vnc/new-emu:5901.log ===================
===========================================================================

Session startup via '/home/cc/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 6831... success!

And the respective log file:
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.12.0 - built 2024-01-23 19:20
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12101004, X.Org


Sun Jul  7 16:36:10 2024
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x55ac5713eb90 for event 2
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x55ac5713eb90 for event 3
3NI3X0 New Xtigervnc server 'new-emu:1 (cc)' on port 5901 for display :1.
3NI3X0 Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/cc/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
xrdb: Connection refused
xrdb: Can't open display ':1'
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.

Not sure what is going on. I just want to access my instance through VNC on my Mac so I can run some experiments using the GUI. Any help is welcome! Thank you!
